# Using SLRequest to post to a Facebook Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slrequest

I can use `SLRequest` to publish to `me/feed`, but I am having issues trying to publish to `[pageid]/feed`.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

I have @"publish_stream" permissions requested.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the permissions have to be granted in two different steps. I was under the impression that basic permission was already included. In case someone needs help with Facebook publishing in general, this helped me:

http://www.stuarticus.com/2012/11/12/ios-6-the-social-framework-reference/

Comment: If you managed to do this eventually, could you share the code? The link in your answer no longer works.

Comment: Hi, my website was redesigned and lost some content on the way...the github repo is here: https://github.com/stuarticus/socialframework

Comment: Website is back! http://www.stuarticus.com/2012/11/12/ios-6-the-social-framework-reference/